# Angular: @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) - NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am sending data from a component page to a dialog.

I am able to receive the data, but when I try to use it in ngFor I get the error:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
> 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

I've looked through 9 different SO articles on this error but I still can't seem to solve.
My original code was:

Typescript:

(interface file)

```
export interface IPersonInternalNotes {
PersonID       : number;
Note            : string;
CreatedBy       : number;
CreatedByText   : string;
CreateDate      : string;
ModifiedBy      : number;
ModifiedByText  : string;
ModifiedDate    : string;
DeletedBy       : number;
DeletedByText   : string;
DeleteDate      : string;
}
```

(component file)

```
internalNotes: IPersonInternalNotes[] = [];
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: IPersonInternalNotes[] //in constructor)
this.internalNotes = this.data; //in  ngOnInit
```

HTML:

```
<tr *ngFor="let note of internalNotes">
      <td>{{note.CreateDate}}</td>
      <td>{{note.CreatedByText}}</td>
      <td>{{note.Note}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Here is what the data looks like in the debugger:

[image: data]

I've tried many variations such as:

```
var myData = Object.keys(this.data).map((k) => this.data[k]);

for (let index = 0; index < myData.length; index++) {
     this.internalNotes.push(myData[index]);
}
```

and

```
this.data.forEach(element => {
     this.internalNotes.push(element);
});
```

and
changing the html to

```
<tr *ngFor="let note of internalNotes.data">
```

but it got the error: “Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IPersonInternalNotes[]”

What am I missing? I must not be understanding something about the data type.

Comment: What is the structure of `IPersonInternalNotes`? Have you tried `this.internalNotes = this.data.data;`?

Comment: @MishaMashina I just updated to show the structure of IPersonInternalNotes.  I tried this.data.data but it says "Property 'data' does not exist on type IPersonInternalNotes[]"

Comment: What do you get if you do `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any` instead of `IPersonInternalNotes[]`?

Comment: @MishaMashina That did it! setting data to any and then doing this.data.data. Thank you!!!!!!